# Unable to use JAR in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have just created my first JAR in Eclipse, just a simple program with a single class Database.class. It is not in a package.

```
public class Database {
public Database() {
int dbInit = 1; } }
```

I have added it as an external JAR to the build path libraries for another project in Eclipse, but for some reason I cannot get `Database db = new Database()`, the default constructor, to work - it's as if the contents of the JAR are not being recognised.

Could anyone please offer any advice on this?

Thanks very much,

M

Comment: Have you used import statements do import this class?

Comment: @Roflcoptr, imports won't help because `Database` is in the default package.

Comment: Can you browse your jar in the Package Explorer of your project ?

Comment: @Twister - Yep, it's showing fine there

Comment: Does it fails at compilation or runtime ? Have you tried to add it as a normal dependency (create a lib folder in you project, copy the jar in it, refresh your project arborescence in eclipse. Right click on the jar and add it to your build path)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. typically this works, so relax: you did some mistake and can fix it.
2. check content of your jar: run
   `jar vft myjar.jar`

You should get output like 
`Database.class`

Check that it is exactly what you get. Your class file must be at the root of the jar.

1. Verify that you are adding it to your second project correctly: Project/Properties/Java Build Path/Libraries, push button "Add external jars...", navigate to the jar and add it.
2. Now try to write in any java class of your project: Datab  then push ctrl/space
   It should complete to Database. Continue coding and enjoy.

BTW: why did you put your class to default package? I'd suggest you to put it into package. It will help you to avoid mistakes. for example probably you have other class named database in your code. How are you planning to resolve this conflict?

Comment: I'm actually unable to check the content of the jar due to restrictions on my work PC - I'm assuming it's because Java SDK isn't installed and unfortunately I can't change this. I'll try to put it into a package and see if that helps, I'll post back when I know.

Comment: I recompiled the JAR after adding a package and it works fine - I'll take this as a valuable lesson on the importance of packages! Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 0):

You might have to rebuild or clean your project.

Answer (score 0):

The build path is not used at runtime. In your run configuration there's a tab to allow you to specify the classpath used when running the app.